# Object expected error in Internet Explorer, but ONLY on heroku, and only after added Devise (I htink)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, heroku, object-expected

Our Rails3 app is a modified version of a prior Rails3 app which did not cause IE7+ to give the dreaded "Object expected" error. And the new app doesn't throw that error when run locally either. But when we run the same code on heroku IE does report "Done, with errors on page" and specifically "Line 2, Char 1, Error: Object expected, URL (url for whatever page is viewed)"

Other than that things run fine.

Any thoughts why we see the errors only when remotely hosted?

Comment: In IE these errors are more often than not caused by stray trailing commas, for instance:

    var myobj = {
        prop: "value",
        anotherprop: "another value",
    }

Note the last property has a comma after it. IE throws a fit when this happens.

Not sure if this solves your problem but it might get you on the right track.

Comment: thx. it was actually including a missing js file so yes that was a helpful answer. I'd tag it as answered if i knew how from a comment! if you wan tto repost as a answer i'll do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. it turns out the issue was related to a missing js file that was being added to the header by default.